# GET request not returning data on success

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Ok this problem is starting to get annoying!

I have this jquery ajax request code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET", 
    url: "/nameCheck.php", 
    data: {addressName: ""+addressName+"", customer: customer}, 
    success: TEST,
    error: reportProblem
});
```

the nameCheck.php looks like this:

```
include_once("db_connect.php3");
$addressName = $_GET["addressName"];
$customer = $_GET["customer"];
$search = mysql_query("select count(*) from Address where AddressName=".quote_correct($addressName)." and CustomerNumber=$customer",$database); 
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($search);
$number_of_rows = $rows[0];
// note quote_correct is just a function to clean up the users input
if ($number_of_rows>1)
    {
        $message ="NO"; 
    }
else
    {
        $message ="OK";
    } 
echo $message;
?>
```

and on success the TEST function looks like this

```
function TEST(data,status){
    alert(data+" - "+ status);  
}
```

Through a log file I set up in the php code - I see the process of checking to see if the customer name exists is working and I get the proper response of OK or NO.

The ajax call is a success too - and the TEST function is called - but no data is present..

Does anyone know why this isn't working?

Comment: Side note: `and CustomerNumber=$customer` is an injection vulnerability, you should check whether it is a number

Comment: Have to inspected the response? Headers, content?

Comment: Mysql error maybe: Try $search = mysql_query("select count(*) from Address where AddressName=".quote_correct($addressName)." and CustomerNumber=$customer",$database) or die(mysql_error()); that way your ajax will return the error message, or even better run the script manually while debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Try having your ajax call look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/nameCheck.php",
    data: { addressName: "" + addressName + "", customer: customer },
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually also state in my get/post calls the return type. (json,html...) and does the returning php function know what to return?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the content-type header in your PHP. The default response is txt/html, jQuery wants JSON.

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```